# Matching 2 NSString values between class methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods

I understand I can't pass instance variables within Class methods, so I am no longer confused what the difference are between the two.

Hence I am a little stuck.

I have 2 Class Methods and they can both take a `NSString` as an argument.

Is there anyway they can be matched up?
Because one Class method has a string which will be a url that needs to be opened up in Safari after a button is pressed and therefore `@selector(openBrowser:)` needs to know what the url is from `JWKObjectView01`

Please tell me there is a way to do this??

I have tried changing it all to instance methods, but the app crashes when I press the button - so I am trying to working this out:-)

Thanks in advance.
PS I know I start with saying that I understand that you can't mix the 2 classes - as far as I know, but maybe I am missing something?

//added Code:

UIView Class
.h file

```
@interface JWKObjectView01 : UIView <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    NSString *string;
    NSURL *url;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
}

+ (JWKObjectView01 *)anyView:(UIView *)anyView
                         title:(NSString *)title
                        weburl:(NSString *)webstring;

+ (void)openBrowser:(NSString *)urlString;
```

.m file

```
+ (JWKObjectView01 *)anyView:(UIView *)anyView
                       title:(NSString *)title
                      weburl:(NSString *)webString
{
    JWKObjectView01 *anotherView = [[JWKObjectView01 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,200)];
    anotherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [anyView addSubview:anotherView];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);

    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openBrowser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [anotherView addSubview:button];

    return anotherView;
}

+ (void)openBrowser:(NSString *)urlString;
{

    //This is where I am stuck and I need the variable - weburl:(NSString *)webString - 

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

.m file View Controller

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [JWKObjectView01 anyView:self.view title:@"OPEN" weburl:@"http://google.com"];
  }
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: "one Class method has a string which will be a url that needs to be opened up in Safari after a button is pressed" - this part is very hard to understand without a code example: the talk about class variables "having" strings sounds suspicious, because the only way a class method can keep state is through static variables and singletones in other classes. I suspect that the problem is somewhere in that area; please post the relevant code of class method `A`.

Comment: Alright - I have added the code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static variable for the url. Initialize it in the `initialize` method (that is not the `init` method). You can of course add a method that sets the static varialbe's value.

A static varialbe, like class variables in other languages, exists only once at runtime.

But they are no class variables. You could get naming conflicts when the name is used for other static variables in other classes too. Therefore make youself familiar with the singleton pattern and consider using it whenever there is a need for a static varialbe.

Some people "abuse" the application delegate object as a containter for values of global character. This may not be "out of the book" but works fine and is quite common. 
However, I beleive that you are far better off with a singleton.

All this assumes that the related URL will carry the same value at a time for all instances of `JWKObjectView01`.